# MSSQL on Linux, adhoc query: 'No transaction is active.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux

I am trying to perform an adhoc type SQL query, I want to send records from an instance of MSSQL in Windows to MSSQL in Ubuntu Server 20.04, the detail is that the reading it allows me and at the time of writing the said message appears, I explain:

When I want to add a record:

```sql
INSERT INTO [LINKEDSRV]. [BDD]. [DBO]. [TABLE] (column) SELECT 10
```

and **it works** for me,

But when I want to use it in an SP (I'm just adding the snippet where I call it):

```
SET @lQryStr = 'DELETE FROM [LINKEDSRV].' + @BDD + '.DBO.TABLE WHERE YEAR (p1) =' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @ lp1,1) + 'AND MONTH (p1) =' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, @ lp1,1)

EXEC (@lQryStr)
```

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LINKEDSRV" returned message "No transaction is active.". Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 312 A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

When I use it in other instances of MSSQL on Windows I have no problem, but it specifically happens to me on linux. Follow the tutorial for the RPC and MSDTC settings, redirect port 135 (RPC) and create the iptables. The user has the necessary permissions, since if he allows me to enter when I call him outside of an SP. Could you help me, I do not know if it is not a new feature allowed in MSSQL in Linux, if this helps both are DEVELOPER versions. I will appreciate your contributions.